# Openmp parallel for loop syntax in linux C with pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, openmp, systems-programming

I had done the below code with openmp, but the function

```
nvme_identify(fd, 0, 1, data);
```

in turn invokes ioctl() which a blocking system call for nvme. So to have true parallelism I am looking to have the same code with pthreads.

I am new to pthreads, so can anybody get me the syntax in pthreads for the below openmp code?

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(5)
for(i=0; i<rc; i++){
      err = nvme_identify(fd, 0, 1, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pthreads unlike OpenMP kinda works manuel.
As a pseudocode you may try something like this:

In `main()`

create a struct for parameters to use in `nvme_identify(fd, 0, 1, data)`
Let's say `my_struct[NUM_OF_THREADS]`
`NUM_OF_THREADS` is (as you gussed) number of threads you'll spawn.

Fill the parametes correctly, i.e.:
`my_struct[0].fd = fd`
`my_struct[0].data = data`
...

create pthreads with a for loop like:

`for (i=0; i < NUM_OF_THREADS; i++)
   pthreads_create(...., MyThreadedFunction, (void*)&my_struct[i]);`

In `MyThreadedFunction(void *val)`
recover parameters like this:
`struct my_struct_tag *my_struct = (struct my_struct_tag *)val;`
`int fd = my_struct->fd`
`...`
and call `err = nvme_identify(fd, 0, 1, data)`

Adjust parameters correctly for maximum parallelism.
In main you'll need to use `pthread_join` to wait for all threads completes.

There may be error here and there in my logic. This is a quick answer.
Hope that helps.